# Assert with groovy in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

New to Groovy and a bit of a novice with coding overall but I'm trying so please bear with me. Apologies in advance if I don't but enough detail as to what I'm trying to achieve here!

I am writing a scripted test in SOAPUI for a SOAP call that has multiple instances of the same named *node ("//ns2:AddOnCode")*. I have expected results of what values I am expecting to return in the instances of this node.

So far I have created the following which works in terms of it only passes if all of these values are present. But I'd like to take this one step further and get the test to fail if this node is returned with a value that I havent defined.

So if say all these 5 values returned but also a 6th `//ns2:AddOnCode` value came with say '999' then I'd like this test to fail.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )

assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('029')
assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('030')
assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('040')
assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('083')
assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('105')
```

Below is my response. You can see there are various instances of AddOnCode and these are what I am intereted in testing. My asserts above succesfully pass as all five of these are present in the response but I need to add a further step to look for any other AddOnCode values that are not in my list of assert values.

```
                 <ns2:AddOnService>
                    <ns2:AddOnCode>029</ns2:AddOnCode>
                    <ns2:AddOnDesc>OVERPAYMENT</ns2:AddOnDesc>
                 </ns2:AddOnService>
                 <ns2:AddOnService>
                    <ns2:AddOnCode>030</ns2:AddOnCode>
                    <ns2:AddOnDesc>REWARDS POOL</ns2:AddOnDesc>
                 </ns2:AddOnService>
                 <ns2:AddOnService>
                    <ns2:AddOnCode>040</ns2:AddOnCode>
                    <ns2:AddOnDesc>NON URGENT</ns2:AddOnDesc>
                 </ns2:AddOnService>
                 <ns2:AddOnService>
                    <ns2:AddOnCode>083</ns2:AddOnCode>
                    <ns2:AddOnDesc>EXGRATIA</ns2:AddOnDesc>
                 </ns2:AddOnService>
                 <ns2:AddOnService>
                    <ns2:AddOnCode>105</ns2:AddOnCode>
                    <ns2:AddOnDesc>MISC NON CLAIMABLE</ns2:AddOnDesc>
                 </ns2:AddOnService>
              </ns2:AddOnServices>
```

Comment: are you talking about not operator? like this: `assert ! holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('999')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the not operator. But I need to apply a not operator if none of my already scripted codes are brought back. Your example would be good to tell me if 999 were to arrive in error but this node could be filled with any value, not just 999. If any value were to return other than the 5 I am expecting then I want the test to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correctly.
Change from:

```
assert holder["//ns2:AddOnCode"].contains('029')
```

To:

```
assert holder.getNodeValue("//ns2:AddOnCode").contains('029')
```

EDIT: Based on OP comments, there are repeating nodes.

Since OP is using **Script Assertion**, below is the script
which needs `expectedCodes` as input and retrieves the `actualCodes` and compares both and fails if not matches.

```
//Please edit if needed
def expectedCodes = ['029', '030', '040', '083', '105']
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'AddOnCode' }*.text()
assert expectedCodes.sort() == actualCodes.sort()
```

NOTE: Matthew, the above is independent code for **Script Assertion** and does not require your existing code.

Comment: If I change all my assert rows in this way the scrip is then failing with the following message.  assert holder.getNodeValue("//ns2:AddOnCode").contains('030') | | | | 029 false com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder@115c3a47 (toString() threw java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: Sorry. Having trouble knowing how to identify text as code here as well.

Comment: Please show your response and mention which data you need to extract.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the response. Hopefully this helps explain better.

Comment: @MatthewThomas, so you need to extract all the values? and assert them? Looks you have repeating nodes.

Comment: Yes, I need to extract all values and assert them. I have been able to do this bit so far. But I also need to assert that no values are coming through that I am not expecting. Yes, I have repeating nodes to add to the complexity.

Comment: @MatthewThomas, so you know the expected code before hand? do not you want to assert descriptions?

Comment: No, I dont need to assert the descriptions, only the codes. And yes, I will know the expected code before hand.

Comment: @MatthewThomas, thank you for clarifying. will update the answer in couple of min.

Comment: @MatthewThomas, Please check the `EDIT` part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. This has worked perfectly. I'm only new here so I'm unable to give you my +1. I'll take this forward with me as I have a lot of similar tests to run this way.

Comment: @MatthewThomas, no worries. [Appreciate if you can accept it as answered then](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).